# Any guides on how to create custom ogg containers

Tags: ogg, opus

I am trying to add both timestamped input and audio to an ogg file.

I am having trouble understanding how to use the ogg format since the only guide seems to be a format specification.

https://xiph.org/ogg/doc/libogg/general.html

So basically, I have to add it to the each input to individual packets and sync multiple packages to a page?

https://xiph.org/ogg/doc/libogg/ogg_page.html

edit: since I got downvotes. My intent was to add a json like time stamp to audio segments in ogg format such that.

```
{ 'time': int32/64, input: 'char' }
audiodata
```

Sometimes, the application may have the JSON commands without the audio data.

I am looking been trying to find guides but it is difficult. I been searching around for a week.

https://wiki.xiph.org/OggKate

I am not even sure oggkate handles situations when there is no audio for extended periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete example of an Opus encoder.

https://github.com/krad-radio/butt-krad-opus/blob/master/src/opus_encode.cpp

Comment: The thing is that I need to mix multiple streams into the opus encoder.

I cannot directly uses opus because they already have their own format from the looks of it. It seems like the only thing that works well is libogg and a few libraries. The rest is so heavily lacking documentation that I wonder about the downvotes itself in this community.